# How can I change the color and action of my button in JS (p5)?

Tags: javascript, button

I'm trying to not only change the color of my button, but also be able to call an onClick() function that links it to the next GUI. How do I do this? I'm using p5 as my IDE.

```
//Load the GUI
let img;
function preload() {
  img = loadImage('assets/main_menu.PNG');
}

//Call the GUI
function setup() {
  createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
  img.resize(img.width, img.height)
  image(img, 0, 0);
}

//Button 1
let button;
function draw() {

  image(img, 0, 0);
  button = createButton('Type Planet!');
  button.position(100, 855);
  button.size(200,50);
  button.color('red');
}
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code and functions (`createButton()`, `position()`, etc). Unless I'm mistake, then aren't native JS functions.

Comment: You should use the built in code editor to include your html as well.